# T-SQL: Single-Query Join with either one Table or another

Tags: sql, t-sql, left-join

My Problem is the following:
Say you have three different tables (Products, Bills and Returns)

```
| ProductId | Name |
=====================
| 1         | Car  |

| BillId | ProductId | Amount |
=================================
| 1      | 1         | 100$   |
| 2      | 1         | 200$   |

| ReturnId | ProductId | Amount |
===================================
| 1        | 1         | 50$    |
```

How would a SINGLE Query look like to get the following output:

```
| Product-ID | Name | Type | Amount |
=====================================
| 1          | Car  | Bill | 100$   |
| 1          | Car  | Bill | 200$   |
| 1          | Car  | Ret  | 50$    |
```

I was trying with all sorts of Joins, and somehow I can't get my head around this.
What am I doing wrong?
The closest solution I have found till now was something like this:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (CASE
           WHEN b.Amount IS NOT NULL THEN 'Bill'
           ELSE 'Ret'
       END) AS Type,
       COALESCE(b.Amount, r.Amount) AS Amount
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN Bills b ON b.ProductId = p.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Returns r ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
```

One thing is very important to me: The real scenario-query is MUCH bigger, and I don't want to copy/paste the whole logic of there query as if it would be the case when using a Union.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The below would work as needed,

```
SELECT  Products.*, 
        [Type], 
        Amount
FROM    Products
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  ProductID, 'Bill' [Type], Amount
            FROM    Bills
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  ProductID, 'Ret' [Type], Amount
            FROM    Returns
        ) transactions
            ON transactions.ProductID = Products.ProductID
```

Comment: Just to clarify why I have posted after other answers is that doing the union in a subquery reduces the number of table scans on products and will made the query more efficient. In this there are 3 table scans and 1 join compared to the other solutions which require 4 tables scans (products twice) and 2 joins.

Comment: This is indeed the best solution, and it worked like a charm! And it's the most uncomplicated one for me. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`UNION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx):

```
SELECT p.*, 'Bill' as [Type], b.Amount
FROM Products p
  INNER JOIN Bills b
    ON b.ProductId = p.ProductId
UNION 
SELECT p.*, 'Ret' as [Type], r.Amount
FROM Products p
  INNER JOIN Returns r
    ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
```

Comment: In the real scenarion the query is much bigger, and I don't want to copy the whole logic. Is there another way? (I'll edit my post)

Comment: @Shion - I believe this is the most maintainable way to do this.

Comment: I think the answer from @johntotetwoo (just above yours) is a bit nicer. Escpecially if I have other joins and a lot of where's.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
(SELECT Products.ProductID,
        Products.Name,
        'Bill' as Type,
        Bills.Amount
FROM        Products INNER JOIN Bills
            on Products.ProductID = Bills.ProductID
UNION
SELECT  Products.ProductID,
        Products.Name,
        'Ret' as Type,
        Returns.Amount
FROM        Products INNER JOIN Returns
            on Products.ProductID = Returns.ProductID) as iTable
WHERE   iTable.ProductID = 1
```

Comment: I'll give that a try, seems very nice :)

Comment: @Shion - How is this different from my answer?

Comment: He has wrapped the union into a table, where i have then a single query-source for other where's and joins

Comment: @Shion - He hasn't. Or at least not with any kind of valid syntax. Missing `FROM` a close bracket and an alias.

Comment: @Martin: Of course he has. Although i agree with the syntax-mistake. The good point is: It' doesn't matter anymore, since GarethD has provided a much cleaner version (even if it's just for me :))

Answer (score 1):

Try a UNION query - something like

```
SELECT *, 'bill' FROM 
dbo.product
INNER JOIN bills ON dbo.product.Product_Id = dbo.bills.product_id
UNION
SELECT *, 'return' FROM 
dbo.product
INNER JOIN dbo.returns ON dbo.product.Product_Id = dbo.returns.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the look of nested subqueries, you can take [GarethD's great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9032048/1366033) and convert it into a Common Table Expression (CTE)

```
WITH Transactions AS (
    SELECT ProductID, 'Bill' [Type], Amount FROM Bills
      UNION ALL
    SELECT ProductID, 'Ret'  [Type], Amount FROM Returns
)
SELECT  p.*,  [Type], Amount
FROM    Products p
JOIN    Transactions t
            ON t.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

#### [Here's a demo in SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/336a8/1)